# How would we set up LoginRequiredMixin? I am Getting following Error

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

**Settings:**

```
    LOGIN_URL = 'login_view'
```

**Views:**

```
class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
    template_name = "login.html"
    login_url = 'login.html'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
login_view = MyView.as_view()
```

**Url:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('blogApp.urls')),
    path("login_view/",view=MyView.as_view(template_name = "storefront/login.html"), name="login_view"),
]
```

And Template is in
./templates/storefront/login.html

**I am getting Page not found (404)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't Create Get or Post Function in the Class View

views.py

```
class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
    template_name = "template_name.html"
    login_url = lazy_reverse('login_view')
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
    def get(self, request):
        # do some stuff
    def post(self, request):
        # do some stuff
```

in Settings :
You need to put the actual URL or user lazy_reverse(YOUR_URL_NAME)

```
LOGIN_URL = lazy_reverse('login_view')
```

this view will work **if the user log in** else will redirect the User to `login_view`

in urls:
You write the Template name in the class so You don't need to write it again

```
path("login_view/",view=MyView.as_view(template_name = "storefront/login.html"), name="login_view"),
```

Answer (score 0):

here you are writing template_name two times(first in view and second time in url )
if your template is in the following directory structure

```
templates/storefront/login.html
```

you only have to describe the template_name in view file and you should also check if
you have registered the template folder in the settings.py file.